# If array values greater than 1 gets error

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop

i have run a loop of array, which throws error if the array's data greater than 1 otherwise it works fine. can you please point the mistake?

**HERE's THE 1st LOOP**

This loop stores the data into array `$resultArr`

```
$resultArr = array();
    $i = 0;

foreach($_POST['item_cid'] as $key => $value) {
//Data for Orders Table
    $cid = intval(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$value));
    $pcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_code'][$key]);
    $pname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_name'][$key]);
    $pprice = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_price'][$key]);
    $pqty = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_qty'][$key]);

    $resultArr[$i] = array('cid' => $cid, 'pcode' => $pcode, 'pname' => $pname, 'pprice' => $pprice, 'pqty' => $pqty);
    $i++;

//Data for Customers Table
    $cname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_cname'][$key]);
    $cemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_cemail'][$key]);
    $cphone = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_cphone'][$key]);
    $caddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_caddress'][$key]);
    $ctotal = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_ctotal'][$key]);

}
```

**HERE's THE 2nd LOOP**

This loop prints the array data from `$resultArr`

```
for ($i=0; $i < ((isset($resultArr[$i]['cid']))); $i++) {
        $message .= '<tr>
         <td>' . $resultArr[$i]['pcode'] . '</td>
         <td>' . $resultArr[$i]['pname'] . '</td>
         <td>' . $resultArr[$i]['pprice'] . '</td>
         <td>' . $resultArr[$i]['pqty'] . '</td>
         </tr>';
 }
```

**Please note:**

This works fine until the `$resultArr` has only 1 record otherwise gets the errors/notices.

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\abc\process.php on line 26
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\abc\process.php on line 27
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\abc\process.php on line 28
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\abc\process.php on line 29
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\abc\process.php on line 30

All of these lines are pointing towards the variables defined after the `$resultArr`

**UPDATE:**

Added the HTML FORM

```
//hidden inputs holds the data from DB (they're never empty)
<input type="hidden" name="item_cid[]" value="78286" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_code[]" value="LS-986" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name[]" value="Product Title" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_price[]" value="8999" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_qty[]" value="1" />

//Data submitted by user (this one also has the data, i'll make sure of it)
<input class="input-text" type="text" name="item_cname[]" placeholder="Your Name" />
<input type="text" name="item_cemail[]"  placeholder="Your Email Address"/>
<input type="text" name="item_cphone[]"  placeholder="Your Phone Number"/>
<textarea name="item_caddress[]"  placeholder="Your Address" class="input-text" rows="2" cols="2" maxlength="140"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="item_ctotal[]"  value="18389"/>
```

**var_dump($_POST);**

```
array (size=12)
  'item_cid' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '78286' (length=5)
      1 => string '78286' (length=5)
  'item_code' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'LS-986' (length=6)
      1 => string 'SL-055' (length=6)
  'item_name' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Bridal Set' (length=10)
      1 => string 'Silver Locket set  (Pendant + Earrings)' (length=39)
  'item_price' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '8999' (length=4)
      1 => string '9390' (length=4)
  'item_qty' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
  'item_timestamp' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '09-04-2015 02:58:59' (length=19)
      1 => string '09-04-2015 02:58:59' (length=19)
  'item_cname' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'John Doe' (length=8)
  'item_cemail' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'john@doe.com' (length=12)
  'item_cphone' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '+165798735678' (length=13)
  'item_caddress' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Xyz Street, Area, State, Country.' (length=33)
  'item_ctotal' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '18389' (length=5)
  'submit' => string 'Submit' (length=6)
```

**print_r($resultArr);**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [cid] => 78286 [pcode] => LS-986 [pname] => Bridal Set [pprice] => 8999 [pqty] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [cid] => 78286 [pcode] => SL-055 [pname] => Silver Locket set (Pendant + Earrings) [pprice] => 9390 [pqty] => 1 ) )
```

**THE PHP CODE OF FORM**

```
<?php
    
    $rnum = mt_rand(10000,99999);
    $dt = new DateTime();
    $current_url = base64_encode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    
    if(isset($_SESSION["products"]))
    {
        $total = 0;
        $cart_items = 0;
        
        echo '<form method="post" action="'.$site_url.'/process.php">'. "\xA";
        echo '<ul>'. "\xA";
        echo '<table>'. "\xA";

        echo '<thead>'. "\xA";
        echo '<tr>'. "\xA";
        
        echo '<th>'. "\xA";
        echo 'Product Code';
        echo '</th>'. "\xA";
        
        echo '<th>'. "\xA";
        echo 'Product Name';        
        echo '</th>'. "\xA";
        
        echo '<th>'. "\xA";
        echo 'Price';       
        echo '</th>'. "\xA";
        
        echo '<th>'. "\xA";
        echo 'Quantity';        
        echo '</th>'. "\xA";

        echo '<th>'. "\xA";
        echo '';        
        echo '</th>'. "\xA";

        echo '</tr>'. "\xA";
        echo '</thead>'. "\xA";     
        
        foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm)
        {
           $product_code = $cart_itm["code"];
           $results = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE prod_code='$product_code' LIMIT 1");
           $obj = $results->fetch_object();
        echo '<tr>'. "\xA";

        echo '<td>'. "\xA";
        echo ''.$product_code.''. "\xA";
        echo '</td>'. "\xA";
        
        echo '<td>'. "\xA";
        echo ''.$obj->prod_name.''. "\xA";
        echo '</td>'. "\xA";
        
        echo '<td>'. "\xA";
        echo ''.number_format($obj->prod_price,0).''. "\xA";
        echo '</td>'. "\xA";

        echo '<td>'. "\xA";
        echo ''.$cart_itm["qty"].''. "\xA";
        echo '</td>'. "\xA";

        echo '<td class="product-remove">'. "\xA";
        echo '<span class="remove-itm"><a href="'.$site_url.'/cart_update.php?removep='.$cart_itm["code"].'&return_url='.$current_url.'" class="remove" title="Remove this product from cart"> &times;</a></span>'. "\xA";
        echo '</td>'. "\xA";
        echo '</tr>'. "\xA";        
        
        $subtotal       = ($obj->prod_price * $cart_itm["qty"]); //Multiply item quantity * price
        $total          = ($total + $subtotal); //Add up to total price
        
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_cid[]" value="'.$rnum.'" />'. "\xA";
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_code[]" value="'.$product_code.'" />'. "\xA";
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_name[]" value="'.$obj->prod_name.'" />'. "\xA";
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_price[]" value="'.$obj->prod_price.'" />'. "\xA";
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_qty[]" value="'.$cart_itm["qty"].'" />'. "\xA";
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_timestamp[]" value="'.$dt->format('d-m-Y H:i:s').'" />';
        $cart_items ++;

        }

        echo '<tr id="scrtop">'. "\xA";
        echo '<td colspan="2">'. "\xA";
        echo 'Total Amount:'. "\xA";        
        echo '</td>'. "\xA";        

        echo '<td>'. "\xA";
        echo '<strong>Rs. '.number_format($total,0).' /=</strong>'. "\xA";
        echo '</td>'. "\xA";        
        echo '</tr>'. "\xA";
        echo '</table>'. "\xA";
        echo '<div class="clear"></div>'. "\xA";

        echo '<a class="order-button">Place Order</a>'. "\xA";

        echo '<div id="order-form">'. "\xA";
        echo '<h3>Place Your Order</h3>'. "\xA";
        echo '<p>Please provide your billing/shipping details to proceed.</p>'."\xA";

        echo '<p class="form-row">
        <label class="" for="item_cname[]">Your Name <span class="required">*</span></lable>
        <input class="input-text" type="text" name="item_cname[]" placeholder="Your Name" />
        </p>'."\xA";
        
        echo '<p class="form-row">
        <label class="" for="item_cemail[]">Email Address <span class="required">*</span></lable>
        <input type="text" name="item_cemail[]"  placeholder="Your Email Address"/>
        </p>'."\xA";
        
        echo '<p class="form-row">
        <label class="" for="item_cphone[]">Phone Number <span class="required">*</span></lable>
        <input type="text" name="item_cphone[]"  placeholder="Your Phone Number"/>
        </p>'."\xA";
        
        echo '<p class="form-row">
        <label class="" for="item_caddress[]">Address <span class="required">*</span></lable>
        <textarea name="item_caddress[]"  placeholder="Your Address" class="input-text" rows="2" cols="2" maxlength="140"></textarea>
        </p>'."\xA";
        
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_ctotal[]"  value="'.$total.'"/>'."\xA";

        echo '<input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Submit" />'."\xA";
        echo '</div>'."\xA";

        echo '</form>'. "\xA";

    }else{
        echo '<h4>Your Cart is empty</h4>';
        echo '<a href="index.php">Continue Shopping</a>';
    }
    
    ?>
```

**THE PHP CODE TO PROCESS THE FORM**

```
<?php
session_start();
require('admin/connect.php');
require('includes/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$resultArr = array();
$i = 0;

foreach($_POST['item_cid'] as $key => $value) {
//Data for Orders Table
    $cid = intval(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$value));
    $pcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_code'][$key]);
    $pname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_name'][$key]);
    $pprice = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_price'][$key]);
    $pqty = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_qty'][$key]);

    $resultArr[$i] = array('cid' => $cid, 'pcode' => $pcode, 'pname' => $pname, 'pprice' => $pprice, 'pqty' => $pqty);
    $i++;

//Data for Customers Table
    $cname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_cname'][$key]);
    $cemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_cemail'][$key]);
    $cphone = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_cphone'][$key]);
    $caddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_caddress'][$key]);
    $ctotal = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_ctotal'][$key]);

$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (cid, ordprod_code, ordprod_name, ordprod_price, ordprod_qty) VALUES ('$value', '$pcode', '$pname', '$pprice', '$pqty')";
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO customers (cid, cname, cemail, cphone, caddress, ctotal) VALUES ('$value','$cname','$cemail','$cphone','$caddress','$ctotal')";

    mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
    mysqli_query($connection,$sql2);

} // close the loop

    print_r($resultArr);
    var_dump($resultArr);
    echo ''.count($resultArr).'';
//********************************
// START EMAIL FUNCTION
//********************************

$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<a href="http://www.example.com/"><img src="http://cdn.example.com/static/images/emailhead.jpg" alt="MY Site" /></a>';
$message .= '<h3>Customer Information:</h3>';
$message .= '<table rules="all" border="1" style="border-color: #ccc;" cellpadding="10">';
$message .= '<tr><td><strong>CustomerID</strong></td><td>'. $cid .'</td></tr>';
$message .= '<tr><td><strong>Name:</strong></td><td>'. $cname .'</td></tr>';
$message .= '<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong></td><td>'. $cemail .'</td></tr>';
$message .= '<tr><td><strong>Phone:</strong></td><td>'. $cphone .'</td></tr>';
$message .= '<tr><td><strong>Address:</strong></td><td>'. $caddress .'</td></tr>';
$message .= '</table>';
$message .= '<br />';
$message .= '<h3>Order Details:</h3>';
$message .= '<table rules="all" border="1" style="border-color: #ccc;" cellpadding="10">';
$message .= '<tr style="background:#eee;">
            <td><strong>Product Code</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Product Name</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Product Price</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Product Qty</strong></td>
            </tr>';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($resultArr); $i++) {
    $message .= '<tr>
         <td>'.$resultArr[$i]['pcode'].'</td>
         <td>'.$resultArr[$i]['pname'].'</td>
         <td>'.$resultArr[$i]['pprice'].'</td>
         <td>'.$resultArr[$i]['pqty'].'</td>
         </tr>';
}
$message .= '<tr style="background:#eee;">
            <td colspan="2">Total Amount</td>
            <td>'.$ctotal.'</td>
            <td></td>
            </tr>';
$message .= '</table>';
$message .= '</body></html>';

$pattern = "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i";
if (preg_match($pattern, $cemail)) {
    $cleanedFrom = $cemail;
} else {
    return "The email address you entered was invalid. Please try again!";
}

//***************************************
// SEND MAIL USING GMAIL SMTP SERVER
//***************************************
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                       // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'me@gmail.com';                   // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password';               // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS
$mail->setFrom(''.$cemail.'', ''.$cname.'');     //Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->addReplyTo(''.$cemail.'', ''.$cname.'');  //Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addAddress('me@gmail.com', 'YAQOOB');  // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('me@gmail.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addCC('');
$mail->addBCC('');
$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->addAttachment('/user/file.doc');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/images/image.jpg', 'new.jpg'); // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'New order arrived from CustomerID #'.$cid.'';
$mail->Body    = ''.$message.'';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
//$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';

} // Data Inserted & Emailed Close IF Statement


session_destroy();

?>
```

Comment: Try to change your for loop to a while loop like this: `$i = 0; while(isset($resultArr[$i][cid"])) {/*Do stuff*/ $i++;}` Does that do the trick for you?

Comment: What is `$i < ((isset($resultArr[$i]['cid'])))` supposed to mean? `isset()` returns `true` or `false`, it doesn't make sense to compare `$i` with it as a number.

Comment: @Rizier123 it did not work & you have a typo in your code. thanks for the help

Comment: @Barmar it suppose to count the number of records in the variable `$resultArr`

Comment: ^ What?! Why don't you use `count($resultArr)` then?! If this ^^ Is your intention, then your current condition is completely wrong

Comment: Why are you using `mysqli_real_escape_string` to escape strings being displayed in HTML? You should be using `htmlentities()`. `mysqli_real_escape_string` should only be used to escape strings being substituted into a SQL query. But it's better to use prepared statements for that.

Comment: @Barmar i'm using `mysqli_real_escape_string` because i'm supposed to do that before inserting it to Database? after the insertion i'm using those variables into the `$message .=` part.

Comment: @Rizier123 i followed Barmar answer, changed the condition, but the errors didn't go away.

Comment: Which lines are 26-30?

Comment: @Barmar line 26-30 is these variables declaration `$cname` , `$cemail`, `$cphone`,`$caddress`,  `$ctotal`

Comment: Can you post the HTML of the form? It sounds like you don't have those fields on every row of the form like you do for the first 5 fields.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Comment: @Barmar its shows the proper data i have submitted :(

Comment: There's no way that `$_POST` is coming from the same form you put in the question. Why does it say `cid` instead of `item_cid`?

Comment: Your `var_dump($_POST)` looks more like `var_dump($resultArr)`.

Comment: @Barmar i run the foreach loop with key value of `item_cid` as you can see here `foreach($_POST['item_cid'] as $key => $value) {` and then in the loop i defined the variable `$cid` which have the value of `item_cid`

Comment: I know you use `cid` in `$resultArr`. But the elements of `$_POST` should have the same keys as the names in the `<input>`, so `$_POST` should contain `item_cid`, not just `cid`.

Comment: @Barmar i didn't have any problems, so i just haven't noticed. because all the data inserts just fine into the DB :(

Comment: If you don't post the real output of `var_dump($_POST)` I give up. The output you posted is impossible.

Comment: @Barmar let me post you the complete code, so you may understand what im saying

Comment: @Barmar please check the updated question, i have completely added the form code and the process code, i have nothing to hide.

Comment: Two problems: 1. You have invalid HTML, because first 6 inputs are in the table, but they're not inside `<td>` elements. 2. The last 5 inputs are not being echoed inside the `foreach` loop, so you only have one of them, not one for each item.

Comment: There's no reason to use arrays for the shipping details. There's just one of them, not separate shipping for each item. They shouldn't have `[]` in their names, and you shouldn't try to access them in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: At the very best of my knowledge i made this code, i don't know any other way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use array notation for the shipping details, because there's just one shipping address for the whole order. So change the form to:

```
    echo '<p>Please provide your billing/shipping details to proceed.</p>'."\xA";

    echo '<p class="form-row">
    <label class="" for="item_cname">Your Name <span class="required">*</span></lable>
    <input class="input-text" type="text" name="item_cname" placeholder="Your Name" />
    </p>'."\xA";

    echo '<p class="form-row">
    <label class="" for="item_cemail">Email Address <span class="required">*</span></lable>
    <input type="text" name="item_cemail"  placeholder="Your Email Address"/>
    </p>'."\xA";

    echo '<p class="form-row">
    <label class="" for="item_cphone">Phone Number <span class="required">*</span></lable>
    <input type="text" name="item_cphone"  placeholder="Your Phone Number"/>
    </p>'."\xA";

    echo '<p class="form-row">
    <label class="" for="item_caddress">Address <span class="required">*</span></lable>
    <textarea name="item_caddress"  placeholder="Your Address" class="input-text" rows="2" cols="2" maxlength="140"></textarea>
    </p>'."\xA";

    echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_ctotal"  value="'.$total.'"/>'."\xA";
```

And change the processing code to insert the customer information just once, not in the loop.

```
foreach($_POST['item_cid'] as $key => $value) {
    //Data for Orders Table
    $cid = intval(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$value));
    $pcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_code'][$key]);
    $pname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_name'][$key]);
    $pprice = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_price'][$key]);
    $pqty = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_qty'][$key]);

    $resultArr[$i] = array('cid' => $cid, 'pcode' => $pcode, 'pname' => $pname, 'pprice' => $pprice, 'pqty' => $pqty);
    $i++;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO orders (cid, ordprod_code, ordprod_name, ordprod_price, ordprod_qty) VALUES ('$value', '$pcode', '$pname', '$pprice', '$pqty')";

    mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

} // close the loop

//Data for Customers Table
$cname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_cname']);
$cemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_cemail']);
$cphone = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_cphone']);
$caddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_caddress']);
$ctotal = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_ctotal']);

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO customers (cid, cname, cemail, cphone, caddress, ctotal) VALUES ('$value','$cname','$cemail','$cphone','$caddress','$ctotal')";
mysqli_query($connection,$sql2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately they do not work. the same condition remains as i asked in my question. as long as i have a single record in the `$resultArr` i can submit the form and message, but once the values becomes greater than 1, i get errors.

Comment: Thank you so much Barmar, you were very helpful. Now i understand my mistake and i'm surely learned from it for the future. Thank you so much..

Comment: It also looks like there's no need to repeat `item_cid` on every row, since it's also the same for the whole form.

Comment: OK, i'm removing it too!

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand is that, correct me if i'm wrong, you have a set of values that repeat eg: `item_code`,`item_name`,`item_price`,`item_qty`. So you have looped through them in the first loop. But does the fields like `item_cname`, `item_cemail`, `item_cphone`, `item_caddress`, `item_ctotal` also repeat like the above. If no, that is your problem. You tried to get the value of `item_cname` inside the loop like `$_POST['item_cname'][$key]`.

If these values does'nt repeat or have only one value then i suggest change your code like this

```
$cname  = $_POST['item_cname'];
$cemail = $_POST['item_cemail'];
$cphone = $_POST['item_cphone'];
$caddress= $_POST['item_caddress'];
$ctotal = $_POST['item_ctotal'];

foreach($_POST['item_cid'] as $key => $value) {
    $cid = intval(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$value));
    $pcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_code'][$key]);
    $pname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_name'][$key]);
    $pprice = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_price'][$key]);
    $pqty = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['item_qty'][$key]);

    $resultArr[$i] = array('cid' => $cid, 'pcode' => $pcode, 'pname' => $pname, 'pprice' => $pprice, 'pqty' => $pqty);
    $i++;
}
```